# Spring Integration endpoint for Gigaspaces

Tags: spring, spring-integration, gigaspaces

Is there a Spring Integration endpoint which connects to Gigaspaces?

As a general point, I am also interested to know what is the best documentation for using Spring together with Gigaspaces. Am surprised that there does not appear to be a lot of material written on this. Is Gigaspaces still the preferred option for scaling Spring applications, or are there better solutions?

Comment: Is the question is "How my application based on spring-integration can easily push objects in GigaSpaces XAP?" or "How can I use the spring-integration framework from my code deployed in GigaSpaces XAP (so collocated with the data)?"

Answer (score 1):

GigaSpaces XAP using Spring as its native configuration. XAP container running Spring container internally.

Every XAP component (data grid node , data grid proxy  , event handler ....) exposed via Spring. IDE integration and Unit tests done via Spring application context.

You can deploy spring app as is into XAP. XAP will scale it and make it HA.

See more:
http://docs.gigaspaces.com/xap102tut/spring-integration.html

http://docs.gigaspaces.com/sbp/spring-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the question is "How my application based on spring-integration can easily push objects into GigaSpaces XAP?" or "How can I use the spring-integration framework from my code deployed in GigaSpaces XAP (so collocated with the data)?"

For the first question, I am unaware of any off-the-shelf end-points. But it is very easy to program: you will have to decorate your pojo (by annotation for example, to say where are indexes etc.)
You can use JMS integration (use GS XAP as a JMS broker), but I don't think it is the best way here...

For the second question, a GigaSpaces XAP application is mainly a Spring context. By default, there is no use of Spring integration, but it is very very easy to integrate as we have already in a Spring stack.